# Flex: Scrolling in datagrids

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, scroll

I have 2 questions about flex datagrids:

1. How can I scroll it automatically to the bottom when new portion of data arrived to it (e.g. I added new items)
2. Strange, but seems it doesn't scroll when I use scrolling wheel, is there any trick about it (especially for mac Users)

Thanks in advance

---

Some changes:

```
public function scroll():void
{   
    trace(chatboard.maxVerticalScrollPosition);
    chatboard.verticalScrollPosition = chatboard.maxVerticalScrollPosition;
}

<mx:TextArea id="chatboard" x="10" y="10" width="310" height="181" text="{chatMessages}" editable="false" verticalScrollPolicy="on" resize="scroll()"/>
```

But actually it don't help. The text area is not autoscrolled :(

---

Seems that 1) scroll is not called after new string is added to chatMessages

Comment: Did you try `datagrid.scrollToIndex(datagrid.dataProvider.length - 1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find here that the mouse wheel scrolls the text area by default.  Are you looking for a different behavior?

As far as skipping to the end goes:

in your TextArea wire up to the updateComplete and it seems to work as you would like:

```
 <mx:TextArea id="textArea1" liveScrolling="true" updateComplete="textArea1_Changed(event);" />
```

then

```
  private function textArea1_Changed(event:Event):void {textArea1.verticalScrollPosition = textArea1.maxVerticalScrollPosition;}
```

finally, you can test with something like:

```
  private function btnClick(e:Event):void{textArea1.text += new Date().getTime().toString() + "\n";}
```

Comment: This solution works! I mean that the box is autoscrolled, as I needed.
(don't know why wheel scrolling is not working) :(
Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) dataGrid.verticalScrollPosition=dataGrid.maxVerticalScrollPosition